# To act as [insert profession]

Tags: word-usage

Would it be correct, in English, to say:

> I acted as an engineer in that company

> I acted as a lawyer in that firm

And, more generally:

> To act as [profession]

Comment: By its nature, to _act as_ one kind of person when you're not is a temporary task, and needs to be regularized either by stopping or by making one the right kind of person to start with.

Comment: @JohnLawler While "acting" is usually expected to be temporary, sometimes it can go on for a long time. I think the Trump administration had a number of "acting" department heads that persisted for years because he never nominated a permanent replacement for those vacancies.

Comment: Anyway, language-wise this seems to be fine.

Comment: Better: I provided engineering services.  I was in the engineering department.

Comment: If you had only 1 role within a company, "acted as" seems like you didn't have a defined role.  However, if you had multiple roles, and wanted to emphasize your ability to mulitask,  it seems like  'acted as'  would take on a positive meaning.